# How to print the return of a Function

Tags: python, output

> So i try create a logging_decorator() which is going to log the name of the function that was called, the arguments it was given and finally the returned output.

> I PUT THIS CODE

```
def logging_decorator(function):
    def wrapper_function(*args, **kwargs):
        print(f"You called {function.__name__}{args}")
        print(f"It returned:{function()}")

    return wrapper_function


# Use the decorator 

@logging_decorator
def my_func(*args):
   return sum(args)

return_total = my_func(1,2,3)
```

> But when the editor gave me the output it gave me this.

```
You called my_func(1, 2, 3)
It returned:0
```

Why it gives me 0 output?

Comment: "Why it gives me 0 output?" For the **same reason** that if you write `print(my_func())` **without** the decorator, it would show `0`. Right now, the way that you call the function in the decorator is indirectly, via the `function()` part of the line `print(f"It returned:{function()}")`. If you want to pass arguments, you have to pass them. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Inside `wrapper`, change `function()` to `function(*args, **kwargs)` if you want to pass the same args that `wrapper` was called with.

Comment: how do I return the sum from my_func(), so far it returns None ??

Comment: got it  return function(*args, **kwargs) to def wrapper_function(*args, **kwargs):

Answer (score 3):

When calling the decorated function inside the wrapper function, no arguments were passed which caused you the error in the output.

```
print(f"It returned: {function(*args, **kwargs)}")
```

Answer (score 3):

sum(()) == 0

you call the fucn without passing any params

notice:
*args can be empty

Answer (score 2):

On line 4, it's currently: `print(f"It returned:{function()}")`

It should instead be: `print(f"It returned:{function(*args)}")`

As, in your code, you are printing the result of `function()` - which is 0 as there are no arguments.